# How to have a slider in flutter with specific divisions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, slider

I want to have a slider in flutter with numbers like .5,1,2,3,4,5,10,15. How is this possible. I know that the divisions creates divisions in the slider that are linear. Is this possible to have my own numbers as each dot instead of a linear slider?

```dart
Slider(
  value: seconds,
  max: 3600,
  divisions:
      120, // this is where i want to have a not a linear division
  label: (seconds / 60.0).toStringAsFixed(1),
  onChanged: (double value) {
    setState(() {
      seconds = value;
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the following snippet is what you are looking for:

```
final List<double> values = [0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0];
int selectedIndex = 0;

Slider(
   value: selectedIndex.toDouble(),
   min: 0,
   max: values.length - 1,
   divisions: values.length - 1,
   label: values[selectedIndex].toString(),
   onChanged: (double value) {
   setState(() {
        selectedIndex = value.toInt();
      });
   },
),
```

This is the result:

[image: iPhone simulator screen recording]

Comment: @littleironical The answer only shows the basic code for the general case. If you wondering about the performance. Try to use state management like provider, bloc, etc. Instead, use setState in a class view that contains many widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Custom widget based on the answer of jnk.sch.

*custom_labels_slider.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomLabelsSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> labels;
  final int selectedIndex;
  final void Function(int) onChanged;

  const CustomLabelsSlider(
      {super.key,
      required this.labels,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.selectedIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
        value: selectedIndex.toDouble(),
        min: 0,
        max: labels.length - 1,
        divisions: labels.length - 1,
        label: labels[selectedIndex],
        onChanged: (val) {
          onChanged(val.toInt());
        });
  }
}
```

Bonus: RangeSlider.

*custom_labels_range_slider.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomLabelsRangeSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> labels;
  final int selectedStart;
  final int selectedEnd;
  final void Function(int, int) onChanged;

  const CustomLabelsRangeSlider(
      {super.key,
      required this.labels,
      required this.onChanged,
      required this.selectedStart,
      required this.selectedEnd});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RangeSlider(
        values: RangeValues(selectedStart.toDouble(), selectedEnd.toDouble()),
        min: 0,
        max: labels.length - 1,
        divisions: labels.length - 1,
        labels: RangeLabels(labels[selectedStart], labels[selectedEnd]),
        onChanged: (val) {
          onChanged(val.start.toInt(), val.end.toInt());
        });
  }
}
```

Usage:

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:custom_labels_slider/custom_labels_range_slider.dart';
import 'package:custom_labels_slider/custom_labels_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() {
    return _MainAppState();
  }
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  List<String> labels = ['0.5', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0', '10.0', '15.0'];
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  int _selectedStart = 0;
  int _selectedEnd = 0;

  void changeSelectedIndex(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = value;
    });
  }

  void changeRange(int start, int end){
    setState(() {
    _selectedStart = start;
    _selectedEnd = end;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            CustomLabelsSlider(
              labels: labels,
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              onChanged: (val) {
                changeSelectedIndex(val);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50,),
             CustomLabelsRangeSlider(
              labels: labels,
              selectedStart: _selectedStart,
              selectedEnd: _selectedEnd,
              onChanged: (start, end) {
                changeRange(start, end);
              },
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Github](https://github.com/bigbott/custom_labels_slider).